# Plotting cdf of binomial distribution with pst-func

Tags: pstricks, plot, statistics, pst-func

I found the amazing `pst-func` package for plotting various mathematical functions including the cdf of a binomial distribution.

With XeLaTeX I can compile (for example in OVerleaf):

```
% Requires XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX, LaTeX compiler!!!!!
% Is not compatible with the pdfLaTeX compiler!!!!
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{pst-func}

\newcommand{\rightEndPlot}{10}
\newcommand{\BinomialN}{4}
\newcommand{\Binomialp}{0.5}
\begin{document}    

% See https://mirror.foobar.to/CTAN/graphics/pstricks/contrib/pst-func/doc/pst-func-doc.pdf
\psset{xunit=0.8cm,yunit=8cm}%
\begin{pspicture*}[showgrid=false](-1.5,-0.1)(\rightEndPlot,1.2)%
\psset{arrowscale=1.3,arrowinset=0.05,arrowlength=1.9,comma}%
\psaxes[labelFontSize=\scriptstyle,xticksize=0 1.07,yticksize=0 \rightEndPlot,tickcolor=gray!50,
Dy=0.1,dy=0.1,Dx=1,dx=1,Ox=0]{->}(0,0)(-0.9,0)(\rightEndPlot,1.1)
%\uput[-90](15.8,0){$z$}\uput[0](0,1.1){$P_{0,15}^{100}(Z=z)$}
\psBinomialF[linecolor=red,fillstyle=solid,fillcolor=yellow,barwidth=0.4,opacity=0.5,LineEndColorL=red]{\BinomialN}{\Binomialp}
\end{pspicture*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

This is exactly what I want except that the red line ends already at around 7, but I want it to go until the right end of the plot. How can I extend the red line to the end? I want to plot the cdf on [-1,10] not only on [-1,7].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looking for the plot option `rightEnd`:

```
\psBinomialF[linecolor=red,
fillstyle=solid,
fillcolor=yellow,
barwidth=0.4,
opacity=0.5,
LineEndColorL=red,
rightEnd=5]{\BinomialN}{\Binomialp}
```

[image]

Comment: Perfekt! In my notation, I can add the option `rightEnd=\rightEndPlot`.